# How do I perform a CVS checkout using Perl?

Tags: perl, cvs

the code below prints nothing. Please help me out in the same.

```
use Cvs;

my $obj = new Cvs cvsroot => ":pserver:pramodh\@129.227.152.22:/data/cvs" or die $Cvs::ERROR;

$obj->checkout(package) || print "ERROR";
my @modules = $obj->module_list();
print "@modules";
```

If I work on the command line it works fine with these commands:

```
[root@localhost pramodh]# CVSROOT=:pserver:pramodh@129.227.152.22:/data/cvs
[root@localhost pramodh]# export CVSROOT
[root@localhost pramodh]# cvs login
Logging in to :pserver:pramodh@129.227.152.22:2401/data/cvs
CVS password:pramodh
[root@localhost pramodh]# cvs co packages
cvs checkout: Updating packages
```

Comment: Pramodh, welcome to Stack Overflow. You can make your questions and answers more readable and attractive, especially those which contain `code`; see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. I edited your posting for you.

Comment: What does your code do if you add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top?

Comment: I got this on adding use strict; use warnings;

Bareword "packages" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at cvs.pl line 7.
Execution of cvs.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your `checkout` argument.

```
$obj->checkout('packages') or warn "ERROR";
```

[`package`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) is a reserved keyword in Perl.